# Python and Button presses

Tags: python, button, gpio

I have a project going right now on a Raspberry Pi running the most current version of Jessie OS. On this project, I would like to incorporate some buttons that would run bash scripts. I've been over the code a hundred time and made like 100 different versions of it and I keep running into the same issue. I'm using `subprocess.call` to start the script but then the program won't accept any more button presses just stuck on that script. I press button on input 7 and first script runs then no other button presses are recognized. I am a Python noob but I like to tinker any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import subprocess

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(7)
    if input_state == 0:
        print "start show"
        subprocess.call('/home/pi/lightshowpi/bin/lights.sh')
        time.sleep(0.5)



    input_state1 = GPIO.input(8)
    if input_state1 == 0:
        print "cleanup"
        subprocess.call('/home/pi/lightshowpi/bin/cleanup.sh')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        subprocess.call('/home/pi/lightshowpi/bin/lightson.sh')
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "just stuck on that script"? Does the bash script execute and then things hang or what?

Comment: the script runs and starts my show then no other button presses are registered I have to Ctrl c to exit

Comment: `subprocess.call()` waits for the command to finish before it returns.

Comment: @jasonharper: How is this a duplicate of that other question? Doesn't seem like it to me...

Comment: I tried subprocess. Popen with the same effect. The command that the bash script runs a single line of code that when I run from the command line take 2 seconds to complete

Comment: @martineau: question has been edited since I posted that, it's no longer running into the same problem (comparing `GPIO.input()` values to True/False, when they are actually ints).

Comment: Brian: I suggest you create a `Popen` instance and call its `communicate()` method to retrieve any output and errors that may be occurring. It's difficult for others to do anything but make suggestions since you haven't (or can't) provide something many (most) of us can run on our own systems to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The crazy thing is I had it working yesterday and kept tweaking and somehow broke it.  I'm running over ssh and the Wi-Fi connection is iffy I'm wondering if it's having an effect on the outcome I'm going to try and run it directly when I get home.  Happy Thanksgiving